# Cordova InAppBrowser executeScript callback

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap, content-security-policy

I try to parse some site and execute script in Cordova InAppBrowser's method `executeScript` on iOS and return some result in callback function, but get this error:

> Refused to load gap-iab://InAppBrowser1249228873/%5Bnull%5D because it does not appear in the frame-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

I understand, that `gap-iab://` scheme should be included to Content Security Policy in `<meta>` tag, but code is executing not on my site and I don't have access to it.

Can anyone suggest a decision to resolve this problem?

P.S. On Android `executeScript` works perfectly.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm experiencing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use nginx to proxy the HTML page you are trying to load.  You'd set up nginx to proxy the site you are loading in the InAppBrowser, and use the add-header to add a Content-Security-Policy in the response with "'default-src' gap: gap-iab:"

The one issue you may have is if the original server already includes a strict Content-Security-Policy, because the strictest content-security-policy will get applied.